# new git repository and already git reset does not work

Tags: git

1) I did `git init` in a folder

2) added some project files

3) I did `git add *` so it added recursively all files

4) I realised that I added a bunch of files I don't want to be versioned, so I wanted to undo the add

5) `git reset` gives me the following error:

```
fatal: Failed to resolve 'HEAD' as a valid ref.
```

6) `git status` still shows all the added files

7) I tried `git reset --hard HEAD` and I got the following error:

```
fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions
```

8) `git status` still shows all the added files

What should I do at this point?

Comment: By default (unless you have configured `advice.statusHints` = false), the output of `git status` includes advice on what to do to stage and unstage content: “`(use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)`” and “`(use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)`”. After an initial commit the second message changes to “`(use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)`”.

Comment: I think he didn't saw the msg because the git status was too long

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
git rm [-r] --cache -- <file>…
```

would be the right command to remove from the index the file you don't want to commit.
Any `reset` command won't work, since you have to any commit yet in your newly created repository.

From the [`git rm` man page](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rm.html):

```
--cached
```

> Use this option to unstage and remove paths only from the index.
>   Working tree files, whether modified or not, will be left alone.

```
-r
```

> Allow recursive removal when a leading directory name is given.

```
<file>…
```

> Files to remove.
>   Fileglobs (e.g. `*.c`) can be given to remove all matching files. If you want git to expand file glob characters, you may need to shell-escape them.
>   A leading directory name (e.g. dir to remove dir/file1 and dir/file2) can be given to remove all files in the directory, and recursively all sub-directories, but this requires the `-r` option to be explicitly given.

Comment: git rm -r --cached for directories and without the -r for individual files worked out. thanks!

Comment: @lurscher: good point. I have updated the answer to reflect the 'recursive' `-r` option.

Comment: When I try `git rm -r -- *` I get "fatal: pathspec '.git' did not match any files".

Comment: hey @Kyralessa, to remove everything, do this: `git rm -r --cached "*"`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to undo your initial commit to git then run the following command in your project directory folder:

```
$ rm -rf ./.git
```

That deletes your local git repository so you can start over with your `git init` command.